# Will there be any data loss from adding a new DC?

Tags: cassandra

In multi dc setup; Let's say dc1 has 9 nodes and we added a new data center dc2 with 6 nodes. We then ran `nodetool rebuild` on the 6 nodes using a source of dc1.  Will there be any data loss?

Answer (score 0):

No, there shouldn't be any data loss.  Even though the number of nodes in the data centers don't match, rebuild will stream data by token range.

If I was building a new DC, this is definitely the approach that I would take.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new DC does not result in any data loss. The `nodetool rebuild` command will simply stream the data from the source DC to the new nodes in the new DC.

Admittedly, your question is a little strange. You must have come across some information that made you believe that adding new nodes/DCs can lead to data loss. If you're willing to update your original question with additional context, I'd be happy to review it and respond accordingly. Cheers!